# jquery validator error nothing happens

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var validator = $("#createaccount").validate({

                    rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true
                    }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        username: {

                            required: "Must enter a username"
                        }
                    },

                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        error.appendTo ( element.parent().next());
                    },

                    submitHandler: function() {
                    }

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="index.php" id="createaccount">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
            <td class="status"></td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I press the "Submit" button.. Nothing happens, What have I done wrong?

I am using: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add error placement element. Add new `span` right after `form` element

Or change `errorPlacement` function body as following: `$(error).insertAfter(element);`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/E7cfb/

Comment: error.appendTo ( element.parent().next());
Doesn't it add the error next to the element? That's what I am trying to achieve anyway